# how to access the value of control in codebehind, that was created by javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

How can I access the value of a control (in CodeBehind) that was created by JavaScript dynamically?

I created the controls dynamically by using the following code:

```
var counter = 0;
var words;
var foo;//span tag 

function add(i) {
    var counter = 0;
    var words;
    var foo;//span tag asp in page where the controls to be added

    if (i == 'ad') {
        counter++;
        //Create an input type dynamically.
        foo = document.getElementById("dynamic")
        tbnam = document.createElement("input")  //textbox
        tbdes = document.createElement("input")  //textbox
        lbnam = document.createElement("Label")
        lbdes = document.createElement("Label")
        before = document.createElement('br')
        after = document.createElement('br')

        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        wordsnam = document.createTextNode("Item")
        wordsdes = document.createTextNode("Descrip")
        tbnam.setAttribute("type", "TextBox");
        tbdes.setAttribute("type", "TextBox");
        tbnam.setAttribute("Id", "tbdynamicnam" + counter);
        tbdes.setAttribute("Id", "tbdynamicdes" + counter);
        lbnam.setAttribute("Id", "lbdynamicnam" + counter);
        lbdes.setAttribute("Id", "lbdynamicdes" + counter);
        before.setAttribute("Id", "bf" + counter);
        after.setAttribute("Id", "af" + counter);

        lbnam.appendChild(wordsnam)
        lbdes.appendChild(wordsdes)

        //Append the element in page (in span).

        foo.appendChild(before);
        foo.appendChild(lbnam);
        foo.appendChild(tbnam);
        foo.appendChild(lbdes);
        foo.appendChild(tbdes);
        foo.appendChild(after);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the form is submitted it will be in the [Request.Form collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can access it easiest in the Request object which will check all collections(QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables)

**JavaScript:**

```
tbnam = document.createElement("input")  //textbox       
tbnam.setAttribute("type", "TextBox");       
tbnam.setAttribute("Id", "tbdynamicnam" + counter);
tbnam.setAttribute("name", "tbdynamicnam" + counter);
```

**Code-behind:**

```
string newval = Request["newelementname"];
```

As mentioned below by [James Montagne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717383/james-montagne), you will need a form element name.

Comment: And you need to give the element a name.

Comment: if you want to access before submitting the form, it's impossible